# /dev/sda does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

Tags: kernel

I'm trying to run Linux kernel in QEMU with this command: `qemu-system-x86_64 -m 4G -initrd initrd -kernel arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage -append "root=/dev/sda" Linux.raw`

But when I run it, I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyxqE.png)

Comment: Hi. I think root should be pointing to a partition. sda is the whole virtual disk.

Comment: @jpbrain I listed the files in `/dev`, but there is no `sda`

Comment: will this help? https://ops.tips/notes/booting-linux-on-qemu/

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you might need to change your append to `/dev/vda`.

On the prompt, you can check by running blkid or lsblk and it will show the root device.

For example, on mine:

```
(initramfs) ls /dev/disk/by-uuid/21e3fd4e-278f-4e27-a3fa-abf88ed5156f 
/dev/disk/by-uuid/21e3fd4e-278f-4e27-a3fa-abf88ed5156f
(initramfs) lsblk
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
mtdblock0  31:0    0  128M  0 disk 
vda       254:0    0    1G  0 disk 
(initramfs) blkid
/dev/vda: UUID="21e3fd4e-278f-4e27-a3fa-abf88ed5156f" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext2"
```

Just to make it googleable, this is the error you saw:

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device.  Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT!  /dev/sda does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!
```